workmanager does not fetch scheduled notifications from awesome_notifications package:Flutter
I use the Awesome_notifications package. I want to bring recurring scheduled notifications, but the problem is when I schedule the notification from workmanager, it does not work. I don’t know why, and when I remove the scheduling code, workmanager brings the notification without problems.
Scheduling:
When I remove this code, the notification comes without problems, but I want to schedule the notification.
 schedule:NotificationCalendar(
     //  allowWhileIdle:true,
       //  preciseAlarm: true,
            hour:18,
            minute:13,
            second: 0,
            //repeats: true,
           
          ),

main:
await Future.wait([
Notify.initializeNotification(),
WorkmanagerServise().init(),
]);

Code:
 import 'dart:math';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/Alaidhikar/sabah.dart';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/main.dart';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/virb_uli.dart';
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
//اذكار الصباح 

class Notify{
  static Future initializeNotification() async {
    //AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
    AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
        NotificationChannel(

      channelKey: 'basic_key',
      channelName: 'chnneladhs',
      channelDescription: 'fghjk',
      importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
      //channelShowBadge:true,
      defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Notification,
      onlyAlertOnce: true,


    ),

     
      ],
       debug: true,
    );
     await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
      onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod,
      
    );
  }

 
 /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification or action button
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    debugPrint('onActionReceivedMethod');
    final payload = receivedAction.payload ?? {};
    if (payload["navigate"] == "true") {
      MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const SabahADH(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }


  static Future<bool> scheduleNotification() async {
     final AwesomeNotifications awesomeNotifications = AwesomeNotifications();
    return await awesomeNotifications.createNotification(
     schedule:NotificationCalendar(
         //  allowWhileIdle:true,
           //  preciseAlarm: true,
                hour:18,
                minute:13,
                second: 0,
                //repeats: true,
               
              ),
      content: NotificationContent(
         //  icon: 'resource://mipmap/shado',
        id:1,
        title: "اذكار الصباح",
       // body: "",
        channelKey: 'basic_key',
        wakeUpScreen: true,
        autoDismissible: false,
        category: NotificationCategory.Reminder,
         payload: {
                      "navigate": "true",
                    },
      ),
      
    );

  }


  static Future<void> retrieveScheduledNotifications() async {
    final AwesomeNotifications awesomeNotifications = AwesomeNotifications();
    List<NotificationModel> scheduledNotifications = await awesomeNotifications.listScheduledNotifications();
    print(scheduledNotifications);
  }
}

workmanager:
    // ignore: file_names, depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/Notf.dart';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/Notf.dart';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/nottfi.dart';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/virb_uli.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class WorkmanagerServise {
 

  void registerMyTack() async {

    await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
    'id77',
    'show Notfadk',
    //frequency: const Duration(minutes: 15),
     
     );



  }
  //init
  Future<void> init ()  async {
  await  Workmanager().initialize(actionTask,isInDebugMode: true);
    //regMyTack
    registerMyTack();
  }
  void cancelText(String id ){
    Workmanager().cancelByUniqueName(id);
  }

  
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
 void actionTask() {
  // show Notv
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData){
   
       Notify.scheduleNotification();
     

    return Future.value(true);

  });

   
  }


I don't know what the problem is.

I tested it and it brings notifications but after 3 hours of the specified time I don't know why is it because of the region??

Do I subtract 3 hours from the specified time?
